# SQL - Linking two tables

Tags: sql, database-design

I have two tables, specifically, they contain standard and specific parameters respectively.

Table1:

```
PKParameter     Name        Unit
     1       Temperature     K
     2         Length        mm
     3        Pressure       bar
```

Table2:

```
 PKSpecParam      Name       Unit
     1           Weight       kg
     2            Area        m2
```

PKParameter ans PKSpecParameter are primary keys

I would like to combine these two tables into a third table which will keep track of the primary keys so I can reference any of the parameters, regardless of the table they are from.

For example:

```
PKCombined     PKParameter    PKSpecParameter
     1              1               NULL
     2              2               NULL
     3              3               NULL
     4             NULL              1
     5             NULL              2
```

Now I would like to use PKCombined primary key to reference parameter
Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I've just started meddling with databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.PKParameter , a.name,a.unit,b.PKSpecParam  , b.name,b.unit 

from table1 a outer join table2 b on a.pkparameter=b.pkspecparam
```

However, this will give out null values if number of entries in pkparameter and pkspecparam dont match

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But now I have a different problem, a one I didn't think through. Do you know perhaps how could i differentiate which parameter belongs to which table? Is there a way to write a method which will get not null parameter and then link it to another table